# Get web vitals of website using puppeteer and web-vitals in NextJS

Tags: typescript, next.js, puppeteer, core-web-vitals

I am building a simple tool in NextJS that given a URL executes puppeteer and returns the web vitals however when doing so I can't retrieve the results it doesn't print anything, what could be the reason for this?

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false,  });
const website = await browser.newPage();

await website.goto(request.url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});

// inject the web vitals library into the page
await website.addScriptTag({url: 'https://unpkg.com/web-vitals@2/dist/web-vitals.umd.js'});

// listen for web vitals metrics from the page
website.exposeFunction('onReport', ({name, value}: any) => {
    console.log(`${name}: ${value}`);
});

const onReport = (data: any) => {
    console.log(data);
}

await website.evaluate(() => {
    webVitals.getCLS(console.log);
    webVitals.getFID(console.log);
    webVitals.getLCP(console.log);
    webVitals.getTTFB(console.log);
    webVitals.getFCP(console.log);
});

await browser.close();
```

Comment: Not totally familiar with puppeteer to be honest but shouldn't you call `page.goto` _before_ injecting the JavaScript rather than _after_ or won't it be overwritten by the new page load?

Comment: @BarryPollard hello thanks for replying I have tried but it is not working (I have updated the code in the so post)

Answer (score 2):

The web-vitals script depends on performance observers that may not fire immediately. In particular LCP is not finalised until there is an interaction on the page, and CLS is not finalised until the end of the page load.

You do use `await website.evaluate(()...` but that only "awaits" for the setting up of the performance observers. You then immediately close the page.

I would suggest navigating to another page, or moving the page to hidden, rather than calling `await browser.close();` immediately afterwards and you may see these being called. This incidentally is what the web-vitals library does itself for it's tests as you can see in the [LCP tests](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web-vitals/blob/main/test/e2e/onLCP-test.js) or the [CLS tests](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web-vitals/blob/main/test/e2e/onCLS-test.js).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer I managed to get the FID what should I do in order to obtain also the LCP and CLS?